# phonegap Android: How to clear datas displayed in label according to selection in dropdown list?

Tags: android, jquery, xml, jquery-mobile, cordova

Hi am new phonegap mobile app developing. am developing in android, using jquery mobile and jquery,
Am displaying in datas in mobile by parsing xml datas, where i parsed xml datas successfully, now my problem is dropdown list: `where my drop down list contains List of weekdays Sunday to Saturday` If i select monday it will parse some datas from xml ans display in mobile `Example: if i click sunday it will display Chicken Biriyani` .then `In drop down if i change a day to monday it has to parse xml and has to display Mutton Biriyani`. `But It displays Both Datas of Sunday and Monday.` `if i change days in dropdown datas getting retained` i dont know how to solved this issue please help me Here is the code which i have tried.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css"/>

        <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
 </head>
     <body> 

     <script type="text/javascript">
function report(period)
{

$(function() {


      var eSelect = document.getElementById('yourSelectID');
    var strUser = eSelect.options[eSelect.selectedIndex].value;
    var order="http://journalonline.in/CRM/orderbooking/day?day=" + strUser;

      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: order,
      data: "{}",
      cache: false,
      dataType: "xml",
      success: onSuccess
    });

    $("#resultLog").ajaxError(function(event, request, settings, exception) {
    $("#resultLog").html("Error Calling: " + settings.url + "<br />HTTP Code: " + request.status);
  });
  function onSuccess(data)
  {

    $("#resultLog").append("<hr>");
    $(data).find("Daydetails").each(function () {
    var a=$(this).find("Productname").text();
    var b=$(this).find("Quatity").text();
    var c=$(this).find("Daystatus").text();
     if(a!="")
    {
        $("#resultLog").append("<br><b> Productname</b>:&nbsp; " + $(this).find("Productname").text());

    }
    $("#resultLog").append("<br><b> </b> &nbsp;&nbsp;"  + $(this).find("").text());
    if(b!="")
    {
      $("#resultLog").append("<br> <b>Quantity</b>:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; " + $(this).find("Quatity").text());
    }
    $("#resultLog").append("<br><b> </b> &nbsp;&nbsp;"  + $(this).find("").text());
    if(c!=="")
    {
      $("#resultLog").append("<br><b> Status</b>:&nbsp; " + $(this).find("Daystatus").text());
    }
    $("#resultLog").append("<br><hr>");
  });
  }
  });
 } 
</script>       
         <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">

     <a href="employee.html"  data-theme="b">Back</a>
    <h1>Bird on Tree</h1>
      <a href="login.html"  data-theme="b">Logout</a>
 </div>
       <br>
       <center><font color="#857240" size="5"><h3>Daywise Reports</h3></font></center> 
     <br>

  <table>
       <tr>


             <td style="color:#857240">Day :</td>

           <td>
          <select id="yourSelectID" onchange="report(this.value)">
             <option value="Select">Select</option>
             <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
             <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
             <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
             <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
             <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
             <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
             <option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>

          </select>
          </td>

      </tr>
    </table>






     <p id="resultLog"></p>


     <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

              <center> <a style="text-decoration:none; color:#FFF;" href="http://www.jtechindia.com">J-Tech &copy; 2014</a> </center>

        </div>
   </div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Please help me how to solve this Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are filling your data in page load have you tried in dropdown change event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the jQuery `append()` function to display your results.  This always adds to any existing DOM elements.  If you want to get rid of the previous content before adding the new content, call the `empty()` function:

```
function onSuccess(data)
{
    $("#resultLog").empty();
    $("#resultLog").append("<hr>");
    $(data).find("Daydetails").each(function () {
    ...
```

API Doc for empty:  http://api.jquery.com/empty/